# Match multiple patterns with grep and print only the matched patterns

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that looks like

```
..<long-text>..."field1":"some-value"...<long-text>...."field2":"some-value"...
..<long-text>..."field1":"some-value"...<long-text>...."field2":"some-value"...
..<long-text>..."field1":"some-value"...<long-text>...."field2":"some-value"...
```

I want to extract out `field1` and `field2` from each line of the file in bash. I want field1 and field2 to appear in the same line for each line. So the output should look like-

```
"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
```

I wrote a grep expression like -

```
grep -E '"field1":"[a-z]*".*"field2":"[a-z]*"' -o
```

But because of `.*` in between, it produces all the all text between those two expressions. I also tried

```
grep -E '"field1":"[a-z]*"|"field2":"[a-z]*"' -o
```

But this outputs all field1s in separate line and then all field2s in separate line.

How do I get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` with `awk` to format the result:

```
grep -oE '"(field1|field2)":"[^"]*"' file | awk 'NR%2{p=$0; next} {print p, $0}'

"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
"field1":"some-value" "field2":"some-value"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sed`:

```
echo abcdef | sed 's/\(.\).*\(.\)/\1\2/'
# yields: af
```

for your situation:

```
sed 's/.*\("field1":"[a-z]*"\).*\("field2":"[a-z]*"\).*/\1 \2/' yourfile
```

if some lines don't match at all, then do your `grep` first, e.g.,

```
grep -Eo '"field1":"[a-z]*".*"field2":"[a-z]*"' yourfile |
  sed 's/.*\("field1":"[a-z]*"\).*\("field2":"[a-z]*"\).*/\1 \2/'
```